# Set List of Objects in Swagger API response

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I want to send a list of objects in the response of an API using Swagger.

```
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ApiResponseMessages.ITEM_FETCHED, 
response = "")
```

I have a class -

```
class Item{
   int id;
   String item_name;
}
```

I want a response like -

```
{
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    }
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    }
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    }
}
```

How can i do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You also can set a *ApiReponse* like this:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ApiResponseMessages.ITEM_FETCHED,
             response = Item.class, responseContainer = "List"
            )
```

It's will return:

```
[
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    },
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    },
    {
       "id" : 0,
       "item_name" : ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 16):

For the new package: `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse`

You need to do this (with `@ArraySchema` annotation):

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "",
            content = {@Content(
                mediaType = "application/json",
                array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Bar.class))
            )}
)
```

Comment: This should be the right answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use of `responseContainer = "List"` as below:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "retrieve items", response = Item.class, responseContainer = "List")
```