# Swagger, how to add file upload

Tags: scala, swagger, akka, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger 2.0.X and akka-http. I want to upload file via swagger ui, but don't know how to describe it into the code.I've tried to use request body with multipart content, but it doesn't works

```
  @POST
  @Path("/photo/upload")
  @Operation(
    summary = "Upload photo",
    parameters = Array(
      new Parameter(
        name = "doctype",
        description = "HEADER, describes uploaded document type",
        in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
        required = true,
        schema = new Schema(implementation = classOf[String])
      )
    ),
    requestBody = new RequestBody(
      description = "file",
      content =
        Array(new Content(mediaType = "multipart/form-data", schema = new Schema(`type` = "string", format = "binary")))
    )
  )
  def startPhotoUpload: Route = post {
        headersMap { headers =>
            fileUpload("filename") {
              case (_, fileStream) =>
                val is = fileStream.runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream())
                handleRequest(
                  documentUploadServiceActorProps,
                  SendPhotoToFurtherUpload(is, headers)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda interesting situation. [Swagger specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) has information about file upload. But I couldn't find a way to write code that would allow me to upload files from Swagger UI using multipart/form-data. It works if you change

```
mediaType = "multipart/form-data"
```

to

```
mediaType = "application/octet-stream"
```

or even more specific type like "image/png"

The downside of this method is that `fileUpload` directive doesn't work with streams, it expects multipart data. You'll have to use `extractDataBytes` instead and it's not that good if you also need file metadata, so you'll need to supply that info differently

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this with some success :

[swagger-akka-http 2.x Set List of Objects in the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996884/swagger-akka-http-2-x-set-list-of-objects-in-the-response)

mainly the trick is to add a case class as :

```scala
 //just for swagger
  case class FileUpload(@Schema(`type` = "string", format = "binary", description = "file") file: File)
```